# Search MultiDimensional Array for Starts With

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array, startswith

I load a database table into a list of string, and then I want to search the list for any row that starts with a specific set of letters

Ex: Find all rows that start with 'ab'

This is my code:

```
Dim matchword as string
Dim listOutput As New List(Of String())   
For Each row In Table
        listOutput.Add({row.Item(0), row.Item(1)})
Next

'Item(0) is a word and Item(1) is a number
```

How do I search the list to find all the entries (in column 1) that start with `matchword`

**EDIT** someone mentioned findAll, how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`List(Of T).FindAll(Predicate(Of T))`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Dim result As List(Of String()) = listOutput.FindAll(Function(entry As String())
                                                         Dim matchword As String = "ab"
                                                         Return entry(0).StartsWith(matchword)
                                                     End Function)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each entry As String() In listOutput
    If entry(0).StartsWith(matchword) Then

    End If
Next
```

Comment: I am looping through 500,000 entries, is this the quickest way?

Comment: It is the quickest and smartest. Probably, `List(Of T).FindAll(Predicate(Of T))` does nothing but call the function represented by its parameter for each item in the list.